# Loop a next button to return showing from the begining

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".container .parts").each(function(e) {
            if (e > 1)
                $(this).hide();
            console.log(e);
        });

        $("#next").click(function() {
            if ($(".container .parts:visible:last").next().length != 0) {
                $(".container .parts:visible:last").next().show();
                $(".container .parts:visible:last").next().show();
                $(".container .parts:visible:first").hide();
                $(".container .parts:visible:first").hide();
            } else {
                $(".container .parts:visible:last").hide();
                $(".container .parts:visible:last").hide();
                $(".container .parts:visible:first").next().show();
                $(".container .parts:visible:first").next().show();
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="parts">A</div>
    <div class="parts">B</div>
    <div class="parts">C</div>
    <div class="parts">D</div>
    <div class="parts">E</div>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Hello, In the code here, I'm trying to make the script return to showing first two divs again if it is the end of the divs, But at the last one it disappears.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your after, do you want it to go  (A,B)  (C,D)  (E,A)  (B,C)... or  (A,B) (C,D), (E),  (A,B),(C,D),(E)...etc.

Comment: @Keith Yes, the last one,  (A,B) (C,D), (E), (A,B),(C,D),(E), Also if keeping it only pair divs only would make the job easier, i have no problem with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I think this should do what your after,  it does the (AB), (CD), (E),  and then back to (AB)....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var step = 0;
        var dcount = 2; //how many divs shall we show..
        var parts = $('.container .parts');        
        function showbits() {
            //loop all parts
            parts.each(function (x) {
              //is our step in range..?
              $(this).toggle(x >= step && x < step + dcount); 
            });
            //increae our step by out div count..
            step = step + dcount;
            //if step is greater than length go back to 0..
            if (step >= parts.length) step = 0;
        }
        showbits();
        $("#next").click(showbits);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="parts">A</div>
    <div class="parts">B</div>
    <div class="parts">C</div>
    <div class="parts">D</div>
    <div class="parts">E</div>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That pretty good, But i'm confused a little, Where exactly do i set the max shown number of divs? in case i wanted to show triple divs instead of double

Comment: @AXAI Ok, updated so you can set the number of div's to show..  Change dcount to 3, to make 3 div's etc.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $arr = $(".container .parts"),       // the whole collection
      index = 0;                           // index at which to start showing
      
  function showNext() {
    $arr.hide();                           // hide all
    $arr.eq(index).show();                 // show the element at index (these two lines could be replaced with a for loop if the number of divs to show is dynamic: (for(var i = 0; i < numberOfDivsToShow; i++) $arr.eq(index + i).show();)
    $arr.eq(index + 1).show();             // show the element at index + 1 (if any, if not don't worry as jQuery takes care of that)

    index = index + 2;                     // increment index by 2 (if the number of divs to show is dynamic then instead of adding 2, you must add the number of divs: index = index + numberOfDivsToShow;)
    if(index >= $arr.length) index = 0;    // if we pass $arr.length then go back to 0
  }
  
  $("#next").click(showNext);              // when clicking the #next button, show the next elements
  showNext();                              // by default show the first two
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parts">A</div>
  <div class="parts">B</div>
  <div class="parts">C</div>
  <div class="parts">D</div>
  <div class="parts">E</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because in your code, once the last visible element becomes invisible, there are no elements visible anymore, so the `:visible` selector can't find any elements. 
Of course there are many ways to solve this problem, but I just want to make a minimum modification to your code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="parts">A</div>
    <div class="parts">B</div>
    <div class="parts">C</div>
    <div class="parts">D</div>
    <div class="parts">E</div>
</div>
<div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".container .parts").each(function(e) {
        if (e > 1)
            $(this).hide();
        console.log(e);
    });

    $("#next").click(function() {
        if ($(".container .parts:visible:last").next().length != 0) {
            $(".container .parts:visible:last").next().show();
            $(".container .parts:visible:last").next().show();
            $(".container .parts:visible:first").hide();
            $(".container .parts:visible:first").hide();
        } else {
            $(".container .parts:visible:last").hide();
            $(".container .parts:visible:last").hide();
            $(".container .parts:first").show();  //only modified these two lines
            $(".container .parts:first").next().show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```